# Receive response from Instagram API call with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, express, instagram-api

To authenticate a user in an app using the Instagram API, you redirect the user to the URL `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code`.

Once the user signs in on this page, Instagram then makes a `GET` request to the redirect URI (`REDIRECT-URI` in the above URL). This call to the redirect URI contains a code which you must then include in a `POST` request to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token` to exchange for an access token which is sent in a `JSON` form in the response.

So I'm receiving the redirect call and making the request for the access token with my Express API and this works fine and I get the form with the access token.

```
app.get('/redirect', function(req, res){
    if(req.query.error){
        console.log('Error authenticating user');
        console.log(req.query.error);
    }
    else{
        request.post(
                     'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
                     {form:{
                             client_id: 'my_client_id',
                                 client_secret: 'my_client_secret',
                                 grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                                 redirect_uri: 'http://localhost/redirect',
                                 code: req.query.code
                                 }
                     },
                     function(error, response, body){
                         if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                             console.log(body);
                             //HOW DO I GET THIS RESPONSE TO ANGULAR?
                             res.json({
                                     access_token: body.access_token,
                                         full_name: body.full_name,
                                         username: body.username,
                                         profile_picture: body.profile_picture,
                                         id: body.id
                                         });
                             return;
                         }
                         else{
                             console.log(response);
                             console.log(body);
                         }
                     }

                     );
    };
```

**My question is:** how to I send the access token (or error response) back to Angular?
In other words, how does Angular receive the response from a request it did not make (since the response I want to receive is from the request made with NodeJS's `request`)?

Initially I tried to make the first `GET` to `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code` with Angular but I don't think this can be done because the user should be directed to the Instagram URL to sign in.

---

**Update:**

When Instagram makes the `GET /redirect?code=xxxxxx`, it sends the request to my API but also changes the page URL to `http://localhost/redirect?code=xxxxxx`. I can receive the access token in my API and send it to my client-side but because of the above URL, the page is just displayed as the text of the response and not my `index.html` with `ng-view`. How do I get the page to be my `index.html` in this situation?

I've tried with angular-router the following ways but neither worked:

```
.when('/redirect', {
        templateUrl: 'views/success.html',
                controller: 'Controller'
                        })
```

and

```
.when('/success', {
        templateUrl: 'views/success.html',
                controller: 'Controller'
                        })
.when('/redirect', {
        redirectTo: '/success'
                        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What I ended up doing** (and I'm not sure this is optimal):

Once I receive the response from the call made from Node, I store the access token from the response, `body.access_token`, in the `req.session.user` object provided by the `express-session` `npm` package and then I redirect the user to the home page with `res.redirect('/#/home');`.

```
app.get('/redirect', function(req, res){
if(req.query.error){
    console.log('Error authenticating user');
    console.log(req.query.error);
}
else{
    request.post(
                 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
                 {form:{
                         client_id: 'my_client_id',
                             client_secret: 'my_client_secret',
                             grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                             redirect_uri: 'http://localhost/redirect',
                             code: req.query.code
                             }
                 },
                 function(error, response, body){
                     if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
                           console.log('Success making POST to Insta API for token, making new session object');
                           console.log('token:', (JSON.parse(body).access_token), '\n');
                           req.session.user = {};
                           req.session.user.token  = JSON.parse(body).access_token;
                           req.session.save();
                           res.redirect('/#/home');
                     }
                     else{
                         console.log(error);
                         res.redirect('/#/login');
                     }
                 }

                 );
};
```

This way, Angular doesn't need to receive the access token after redirecting the user to Instagram's authorization page because the access token is saved in the `req.session.user` object which is then accessible on the backend for the duration of the session.

You can then use the access token in any requests to the Instagram API from your backend (initiated by a call to your API from Angular), e.g. by concatenating it to whatever the endpoint is for your Instagram API call like so:

`var endpoint = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=' + req.session.user.token;`

This method also works well with the session management functionality of `express-session` since a session is only created when the user can be authenticated by Instagram. See [here](http://technikyle.com/expressjs-session-tutorial/) for a quick tutorial on how to integrate session management into your app.